# Результат запроса MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

есть, к примеру, запрос - `UPDATE table SET Pass = 123 WHERE Name = Mark`

как мне узнать был ли установлен пароль не делая лишних запросов? то есть сработал ли это запрос как должен... **имени Mark в базе может и не быть**(вот зачем это)

Comment: mysqli_affected_rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [функцию](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.affected-rows.php) `mysqli_affected_rows`, которая вернет число строк затронутых в предыдущем запросе.

Answer (score 0):

Выберите пользователя с именем Марк, и если результат пустой, то  запрос на обновление не выпольнять.